# Express Typescript app build issue within Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, express

I have an issue building my typescript Express app using Docker, but the build works fine outside Docker!
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY ./ ./
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

And this is the error message:

```
Step 10/12 : RUN yarn build
 ---> Running in 2dd76ff2ecca
yarn run v1.22.5
$ tsc
src/config/passport.ts(5,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../dao/userDAO' or its corresponding type declarations.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: Service 'sefare-api' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c yarn build' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error if you move `node_modules` somewhere else, and then rerun `yarn install` and `yarn build`?

Comment: @jakub sorry, I didn't get your idea!

Comment: If you remove `node_modules` on your local machine and re-install all the packages, do you reproduce the error?

Comment: @jakub as I said in my question, the build works fine outside Docker. The problem occurs when I try to build the docker image

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed this issue by changing the name of the file responsible for the bug from **userDao.ts** to ***user-dao.ts*** that did the trick! didn't get the cause though
Hope this will help someone.